# How to Add class or Id to a Ext.Msg.alert box

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I want to add a specific style to a particular Ext alert box (Not a common style for all the alert boxes).

So, how to Add class or Id to a Ext.Msg.alert box ?

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Changes saved successfully.');
```

Comment: It's good practice to add code whenever you ask question !!

Comment: NovusMobile is correct, please read the following article to learn how we ask questions on Stack Overflow [ask]. A well-asked question always elicits a better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend switching instead to use `Ext.Msg.show` instead of `Ext.Msg.alert`. The following code example shows an `alert type` (whit just on button) message which allows to set a class name for styling.

Since you did not provide specific code, this is just a basic example:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
   title: 'Alert',
   msg: 'Your message here',
   buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
   cls: 'your css class here'
});
```